# Pass javascript value to razor

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm not sure why the following code is not passing the variable to be displayed on the page.  This code is all written in a razor webpage, Edit.cshtml.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
                            $(document).ready(function () {
                                $("#body input[name='RoleList']").click(function () {
                                    if ($('input:radio[name=RoleList]:checked').val() == @ViewBag.SelectedRoleID)
                                    {
                                        var num = 1;
                                    $.ajax({
                                        url: 'Account/Edit',
                                        type: 'POST',
                                        data: { num: num },
                                        success: function(result) {
                                            // TODO: do something with the result returned by the 
                                            // foo.cshtml template
                                        }
                                    })
                                    }

                                });
                            });
                        </script>

                            var num = Request["num"];
                            Response.Write(num);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up not having to pass the value from javascript to razor and just used jquery to configure the fields. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to save your ViewBag.value in variable

```
@{
  var value = ViewBag.SelectedRoleID
}
```

if I understand your problem it will help u.

Comment: okay, I tried adding the code and the variable num is still not being passed to the razor page.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the mistake:

Instead of this:

```
if ($('input:radio[name=RoleList]:checked').val() == @ViewBag.SelectedRoleID)
```

you need to do like this:

```
if ($('input:radio[name=RoleList]:checked').val() == '@ViewBag.SelectedRoleID')
```

and one more thing, don't pass url this way, always pass relative url generated by `Url.Action`|helper.

Instead of this:

```
url: 'Account/Edit'
```

always write:

```
url: '@Url.Action("Edit","Account")'
```

and here is answer on **passing javascript variable to razor**:

You are missing a fundamental understanding here. I already answered a version of this question by you, however I did not think you misunderstood this point.

You cannot pass anything from javascript to razor without going through the server.

That is because the razor is executed server side (hence the c# in it). The controller is called, that class is instantiated, then the method is invoked which matches the action requested, and then a view is returned. When the view is returned, the c# code in the view is executed. Once all code has been executed, it issues the html page in the response and then the javascript runs on the client. For you to get from javascript to razor, you would have to issue a new request to go through that path from the beginning in order to come back out in the end.

Solve this issue server side.

Comment: Okay, I made both changes, but the num variable is still not being displayed on the page.

Comment: you can pass razor variable to javascript but not javascript to razor.

Comment: so how do i pass the javascript value to razor going through the server?

Comment: use hidden field and post it in form or send another ajax call, it depends on your scenario  and business logic and requirement

Comment: could i do this using json?

Comment: Yes send an Ajax call and send javascript value to server

Answer (score 0):

In you particular case there is no need to make an AJAX request to chahge the value: you may just do it directly with jQuery without calling the server-side.

Or you'd better use WebAPI for this - as it is more suitable for such cases.

But if you really want to do it with MVC.

In AccountController in Edit action you may get your data as following:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int num) { /* ... */ }
```

Name of the argument should match the POST key in your AJAX request.

Also you shoud create a PartialView, which will be returned from your Edit controller method.

In your AJAX success handler you will receive the actual rendered HTML code of the PartialView and with the means of jQuery, or pure JS if you want, place it into the place on the page you need.

Example of Controller Method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(int num){
   ViewBag.Num = num;
   return PartialView("TestPartialView");
}
```

Example of PartialView (should be a separate file with TestPartialView.cshtml name).

```
@ViewBag.Num
```

And your code modified finally:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                            $(document).ready(function () {
                                $("#body input[name='RoleList']").click(function () {
                                    if ($('input:radio[name=RoleList]:checked').val() == @ViewBag.SelectedRoleID)
                                    {
                                        var num = 1;
                                    $.ajax({
                                        url: '@Url.Action("Edit","Account")',
                                        type: 'POST',
                                        data: { num: num },
                                        success: function(result) {
                                           $("#container").html(result);
                                        }
                                    })
                                    }

                                });
                            });
                        </script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

The result should appear in the last div.

But I should mention here that this solution is just an example for better understanding here an I would not recommend to apply such practice.

Comment: I have modified the code, but the viewbag and the div container results are not displaying.

Comment: You should probably apply the recommendation concertining using url: '@Url.Action("Edit","Account")' also. I've just tested it - it worked just fine.